# Implementing parallax slider in blog

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, blogger

I'm attempting to add a parallax slider to my blog using javascript.

In my research to achieve this I came across this [tutorial](http://www.bloggertipspro.com/2012/12/add-slider-to-blogger.html) about including slider to a blog. I followed the procedure given to implement a different slider (Mary Lou's Parallax slider) using the tutorial. The zip file contained **three javascript files but I referenced only one of them** (uploading it on a page in google sites) in the blogger template. Next I added the css, uploaded the navigation images and background images to the blog and extracted their link and lastly I added the html which I have quoted below:

```
<div id="pxs_container" class="pxs_container">
<div class="pxs_bg">
    <div class="pxs_bg1"></div>
    <div class="pxs_bg2"></div>
    <div class="pxs_bg3"></div>
</div>
<div class="pxs_loading">Loading images...</div>
<div class="pxs_slider_wrapper">
    <ul class="pxs_slider">
        <li><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ytZq9IQR2pA/Ucfbyp3gqII/AAAAAAAAACg/FrLRuE8lsGY/s1600/1.jpg" alt="First Image" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GOiswNwepaA/UcfbxPrx0yI/AAAAAAAAACY/orZUpjDa8_8/s1600/2.jpg" alt="Second Image" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-tkqv4l0OW-o/UcfbvyPcA_I/AAAAAAAAACQ/SdsW2kEmRrE/s1600/3.jpg" alt="Third Image" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-9sWga6Z1-b4/UcfbupMObgI/AAAAAAAAACI/NNH4v7GoWPs/s1600/4.jpg" alt="Fourth Image" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-mQV4AV6cuxA/UcfbtqN14WI/AAAAAAAAACA/Jjn7RKmpDrs/s1600/5.jpg" alt="Fifth Image" /></li>
         <li><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-3Ldx-SSb8So/UcfbsuOUCyI/AAAAAAAAAB0/LiI3qwOi90Q/s1600/6.jpg" alt="Sixth Image" /></li>
                </ul>
    <div class="pxs_navigation">
        <span class="pxs_next"></span>
        <span class="pxs_prev"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="pxs_thumbnails">
        <li><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ytZq9IQR2pA/Ucfbyp3gqII/AAAAAAAAACg/FrLRuE8lsGY/s1600/1.jpg" alt="First Image" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GOiswNwepaA/UcfbxPrx0yI/AAAAAAAAACY/orZUpjDa8_8/s1600/2.jpg" alt="Second Image" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-tkqv4l0OW-o/UcfbvyPcA_I/AAAAAAAAACQ/SdsW2kEmRrE/s1600/3.jpg" alt="Third Image" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-9sWga6Z1-b4/UcfbupMObgI/AAAAAAAAACI/NNH4v7GoWPs/s1600/4.jpg" alt="Fourth Image" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-mQV4AV6cuxA/UcfbtqN14WI/AAAAAAAAACA/Jjn7RKmpDrs/s1600/5.jpg" alt="Fifth Image" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-3Ldx-SSb8So/UcfbsuOUCyI/AAAAAAAAAB0/LiI3qwOi90Q/s1600/6.jpg" alt="Sixth Image" /></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I was expecting the several image and the sliding effect however it just loads forever as shown in the below screen shot

[image: Loading forever]

The live site can be seen here: http://a-mouthful-of-recipes-about-us.blogspot.in/.

I'm unsure what I've missed from my html, what do I need to include to ensure the images and slider appear?

Comment: I think a great amount of code could be deleted here. I don't see why the first section would be necessary for understanding the problem.

Comment: @qben: I though just in case because last time I asked a question, I was requested to produce a code!

Comment: @Payo Incidently at the bottom of your question (next to share, edit etc) do you have a reopen button, if so click it and it will nominate this question for reopening (I notice this on one of my own questions, but I was one of the close voters as well (I know weird) so that may be different). You'll only be able to do this once though so make sure the question is as good as it can be

Comment: @RichardTingle: I can only see share, edit, delete and flag buttons. Moreover I can't find any site on the internet that gives good tutorial about using these slider scripts, alas!

Comment: @Payo Fair enough, there must be something different on my meta question

Comment: @AndrewBarber I've tried to help Payo improve this question sufficiently for reopening and we've made some progress (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185535/reputation-decreases-for-asking-coding-errors). As the original closer do you have any additional suggestions?

Comment: @RichardTingle This looks a bit better. Reopening it now. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Thank u so much for reopening and reconsidering my question. I hope I get help from here.